# countTo.js restart on complete with a short pause

Tags: javascript, jquery

im using the countTo.js script to display a counter. This counter has to count up to a specific value and then restart after a short delay. Everything works fine except the delay after its finished. Problem is, it restarts immediately. Cant get it to work, maybe you got some ideas?
script and documentation on github: [countTo.js](https://github.com/mhuggins/jquery-countTo)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.timer1').countTo({
    onComplete: function() {
     jQuery('.timer1').countTo('restart')
    }
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robboe/pdqht0yx/light/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.timer1').countTo({
    onComplete: function() {
      setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('.timer1').countTo('restart');
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

Here `1000` is the wait in milliseconds.